# Get and pass value of input by url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying get a value of phone from `input` and pass it by url for so call a method to delete it. I have:

```
<div class="telefones">
<%= f.fields_for :phones do |p| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">

      <%= p.text_field :number, :name => 'phone', :class => 'text_field', :type => "text", :data => { :mask => "99 9999.9999"} %>

      <%= link_to 'Delete Phone', "/admin/clinics/"+PHONE_NUMBER+"/delete-phone" %>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In `PHONE_NUMBER`, will be where I will spend the number of this input. Any idei how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible the way you're trying to do that. I would suggest to 2 another approachs:

- Send that form to an particular action, and there, you get the value of phone number input, and delete it
- You could use jquery to get the input value and send a http request to that `"/admin/clinics/"+PHONE_NUMBER+"/delete-phone"` URL, so you could replace the PHONE_NUMBER with the value you just got.

Anyway, since that value is being inputed by the user, you should do some checks and validations. It's not quite simple.
Hope this helps you. Good luck!